# How to run Node.js app on Now.sh/Vercel after build into dist folder

Tags: node.js, vercel, babel-node

I have the following scripts in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION babel src -d dist --copy-files",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
  },
```

My application builds, but only the `dist/index.js` is just served up as a file rather than being run.

I have tried to change `serve` to `start` but no luck.

Have also tried to run the `serve` script as part of the `build` with `&&` - this yielded a build process that just runs.

I feel like the solution is trivial, and I am just making mistake with my scripts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Vercel is a static-first platform. You can't lift a server inside the platform and for that reason, it is not possible to use a classic "listen" approach.

Take a look at [vercel.com/new](https://vercel.com/new) and also a few [examples](https://github.com/zeit/now/tree/master/examples).

Comment: next.js with server render is working well and it is not statis. why they removed documentation about now.json like

{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you either you leverage the vercel serverless `functions` config, or you set it up the old way, using a `vercel.json` file that contains:

once you deploy your code to vercel, you need to :

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since you are using the `builds` `vercel.json` option, you need to ensure all the dependencies, like the compiled `dist` folder and the `node_modules` are uploaded.

Comment: I have tried both previously, none worked well, due to lack of documentation.

I ended up opting for Netlify and proper lambdas.

Comment: Are you using the "builds" definition on vercel.json? Have you verify that the "dist" files are uploaded to vercel ( use the vercel file explorer to verify ).
This is the approach that is working for me right now, on a node express app, done in typescript

Comment: @BenS you solved it? I have src as the main folder where is index.ts and other necessary folders and after build, I have the dist folder, also config the vercel.json file but there I got errors.